# Reference to minipage

Tags: cross-referencing, minipage, labels

I want a reference to the first picture in the minipage but my code doesn't work. I've searched quite a while, but couldn't find any solution. I've also tried thins like sublabel{}, but it didn't work either. Here is my code so far:

Here is a mwe, I can reference to Figure 1 but not to one specific picture in the minimap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.4 \linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.20]{graphisch_r=3,35.jpg}
    \subcaption{(a)}
    \label{fig:graphisch_r=3,35}
    \end{minipage} 
    \hspace{.1\linewidth}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.4 \linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.20]{rechnerisch_r=3.35.jpg}
    \subcaption{(b)}
    \label{fig:rechnerisch_r=3,35}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{(a): Graphische Iteration der logistischen Gleichung für $r=3,35$. (b): Berechnete Werte der ersten $22$ Iterationen der logistischen Gleichung für $r=1$.}
    \label{fig:graphisch_rechnerisch_r=3,35}
\end{figure} \\ \\

In Abb. \ref{fig:graphisch_rechnerisch_r=3,35} \ref{fig:graphisch_r=3,35} erkennt man, dass sich die graphische Iteration gegen zwei Punkte der 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: If I guess enough missing packages to compile your code, I  get https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKeXV.png

Answer (score 1):

If you add the package [subfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig), you can use `\subfloat[caption]{image}` to add captions to sub-figures and then reference them. The additional macro `\subref{}` returns only a label of a sub-figure in parenthesis, while the regular `\ref{}` returns a combined label, e.g. `(a)` and `1a`, respectively. A starred version of `\subref{}` gives a simple label without parenthesis.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbh] %[H] - requires \usepackage{float}
    \centering
    \subfloat[First figure]{%
        \label{fig:first-figure}%
        \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image}}
    \hspace{.1\linewidth}%
    \subfloat[Second figure]{%
        \label{fig:second-figure}%
        \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image-16x9}}
    \caption{\protect\subref{fig:first-figure}: Graphische Iteration der logistischen Gleichung für $r=3,35$. \protect\subref{fig:second-figure}: Berechnete Werte der ersten $22$ Iterationen der logistischen Gleichung für $r=1$.}
    \label{fig:graphisch_rechnerisch_r=3,35}
\end{figure}

In Abb. \ref{fig:graphisch_rechnerisch_r=3,35} \ref{fig:first-figure} erkennt man, dass sich die graphische Iteration gegen zwei Punkte der.
\end{document}
```